# Easy way to get a wxTextCtrl click event?

Tags: wxwidgets, wxtextctrl

Is there an easy way to handle when a user clicks on a wxTextCtrl? After reading the docs [wxTextCtrl](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8.4/wx_wxtextctrl.html) I see that there isn't a click or double click event. I understand that there is no such thing as "click" events in wxWidgets from the question [wxWidgets: Detecting click event on custom controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98941/wxwidgets-detecting-click-event-on-custom-controls), so a simple mouse down event will do.

**Example answer:**

From: [wx wiki](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/WxTaskBarIcon)

```
    textCtrl->Connect(wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN,
              wxMouseEventHandler(MyClass::OnClick), NULL, this );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to handle the *wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN* and *wxEVT_LEFT_UP* events for your text control? Either by adding them to the static message map, or by calling *Connect()* for the handler methods.

**Edit:**

Not all events are listed in the documentation of a class. You need to go up in the hierarchy as well, from *wxTextCtrl* to *wxControl* to *wxWindow*. Unfortunately I can find the documentation for the mouse events in neither class. It should still be possible to handle them, even if it is not clearly documented.

Comment: No, I don't see that event listed at http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8.4/wx_wxtextctrl.html. Are those event for hooking mouse events in general via the wxMouseEvent class or is there event there, but just hidden? I'm using Code::Blocks for the GUI designer and it doesn't show any events for the mouse i.e. "selected" or "activated." Where should I go from there? I have no problem writing the code without the designer. Thanks.

Comment: Can you show me an example Connect() call? My connect line looks like this: Connect (IS_TEXTCTRL1,  wxEVT_LEFT_DOWN, (wxObjectEventFunction) & MyClass::OnTextMouseDown); Everything compiles just fine but MyClass::OnTextMouseDown never gets called. Thanks for the help.

Comment: IS_TEXTCTRL1 should be ID_TEXTCTRL1

Comment: I should also point out that MyClass::OnTextMouseDown is defined as void MyClass::OnTextMouseDown( wxMouseEvent& event), which may or may not be incorrect

Comment: It looks like you have made it to work, great. There are several ways to use the dynamic event handling, unfortunately the event sample is a little dated and doesn't show everything. Documentation is scarce, and may even be wrong (see http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Using_Connect_To_Add_Events_To_An_Existing_Class) - I have found it best to read the wxWidgets source and header files.